# Subtract two count values with different where clause in influxDb

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I have a measurement in influxDb with two keys: `operation` and `count`. The `operation` key can store two different values: 'add' and 'delete'.

I want to subtract the sum(count) value when operation='delete' to sum(count) value when operation='add'.

The following query is supported in mysql but it throws and error in influxql:

`select (select sum(count) from measurement where operation='add') - (select sum(count) from measurement where operation='delete');`

How can this be done using a single influxql query ? I don't think influxql allows two different where clauses in this case.

Comment: The influxDb version is 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InfluxQL doesn't support this kind of multiquery math. You will need to calculate it on the app level.